# curl: no URL specified! running on pm2

Tags: curl, pm2

I am using pm2 to deploy my staging project and in the `pre-deploy-local` I want to send a message to my teammates through slack. Here is the command:

```
    "pre-deploy-local": "curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data '{\"text\":\":space_invader: Deploy staging web with PM2 \"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxxxxx"
```

But it shows this `curl: no URL specified!` error. How can I fix this?

Cheers